# Javascript get localized weekday without a DateTime object

Tags: javascript, weekday

I at the moment have the day values as strings. (e.g. `"monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"`) but no date.

The days describe opening hours of a shop and I would like to translate these string values dynamically based of the locale set on the shop.

I noticed that JS have the wonderful method `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()` but it doesn't seem like that I can get the localized string without providing a date. How would you go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dummy date based on the weekday, choosing the year and month such that a day value of 0 matches a Sunday (yes, you can specify the 0th day too).

Then you can use `toLocaleDateString` with the date to ask for the translated weekday string.

(I also invoked an `Intl.DateTimeFormatter` here to get the user's default locale, because we cannot specify an options object without also specifying a locale.)

```js
const WEEKDAYS = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday']

function translateWeekday (weekdayString) {
  const weekdayIndex = WEEKDAYS.indexOf(weekdayString.toLowerCase())
  if (weekdayIndex < 0) throw new Error(`Unknown weekday "${weekdayString}"`)

  const dummyDate = new Date(2001, 0, weekdayIndex)
  const locale = new Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale

  return dummyDate.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: 'long' })
}
```

On my machine with German locale, `translateWeekday('Wednesday')` returns `'Mittwoch'` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`Date.prototype.getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

```js
// First day of the week depends on the order of this array
const weekdays = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

const date = new Date();

// get first day of week, and then add the weekday

let day = date.getDate() - date.getDay() + weekdays.indexOf(prompt("Day?", "Monday"));

date.setDate(day)

console.log(date.toString());
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was how to convert an English week day string to a translated one based on the locale.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date() perhaps

// current date

```
let date = new Date();
```

Additionally, we can get a day of week:

```
getDay()
```

Get the day of week, from 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday).

When using the Date() method you can also check for year, month, day and time. Maybe if you want to check so that it´s not on christmas day or after closing hours etc. Should work fine!

Methods:

```
getFullYear()
```

Get the year (4 digits)

```
getMonth()
```

Get the month, from 0 to 11.

```
getDate()
```

Get the day of month, from 1 to 31, the name of the method does look a little bit strange.

```
getHours(), getMinutes(), getSeconds(), getMilliseconds()
```

Get the corresponding time components.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was how to convert an English week day string to a translated one based on the locale.

Comment: This was my first approach, but the date is not of the essence here. In fact I am not the one handling whether the shop is closed or not, I get that information from the backend team :) so my only real task here is to get "monday" translated into "montag" if it's a German shop we're talking about. I don't know if it's at all possible without a date object to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new date object pointing to any Monday, then add days consecutively while calling `date.ToLocaleDateString(LOC, {weekday: 'long'})`, replace `LOC` with any locale you wish to use, to define in which language you'd like to get the week names.

```js
function listDayNames(elem, locale)
{
  let e = document.getElementById(elem);
  let date = new Date('2022/08/22');
  for(let i=0;i<=6;i++) {
    e.innerHTML += date.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: 'long' }) + '<br>';        
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  e.innerHTML += '<hr>';
}

let date = new Date();
listDayNames('days', 'en-US');
listDayNames('days', 'de-DE');
```

```html
<p id="days"></p>
```